# Conversion of data during alteration of column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to convert the data type of a column from string to integer. The column has some string values in it.

When doing `table.c.emp_no.alter(type=Integer)`, I get this error:

> OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'terwte' for column 'newColumn' at row 1")
>   '\nALTER TABLE test.mytable CHANGE COLUMN `newColumn` `newColumn` INTEGER' ()

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

By default, MySQL is enabled with strict_mode ON.

Open your "my.ini" file within the MySQL installation directory, and look for the text "sql-mode" and comment-out.

```
#sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: I didn't get your answer Ashwin.Could you please explain bit more.

Comment: You are getting that error because the strict_mode is ON and "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" is enabled. So you can remove the "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" or comment-out "sql-mode" so that you can change the datatype without an error.